# AngularJS reCaptcha not resetting after successful form submission

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

I'm using AngularJS reCaptcha to prevent from spam messages. I'm getting the reCaptcha response after successful resolve of the captcha, but the problem is when I'm submitting the form the checkbox is not resetting and I'm getting the previous captcha response. I don't get it where I went wrong.

I followed the tutorial from this link
[VividCortex/angular-recaptcha](https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to reset it yourself in $http callback

```
this.response = null;
vcRecaptchaService.reload(this.widgetId);
```